# RSpec: difficulty testing the assignment of an array of objects in the index action for different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller

I am writing a spec to test my readinglist controller. The a readinglist has a user_id and a micropost_id. I am trying to create 2 different users and test that the index action will display an list of the users readinglists. The tests below work until its gets to last test for user 2 - whats expected is the reading_list_two but what its getting is the @microposts that correspond to reading_list_one but I can't see why. I am sure its a simple issue of logic but I can't see it.

```
  RSpec.describe ReadingListsController, type: :controller do

   before(:example) do
    login_member
    @user = @member.user
    @another_user = create(:user)
    @micropost = create(:micropost)
    @another_post = create(:micropost)
   end

  describe "Reading list index action" do

  before(:example) do
    create_list(:reading_list, 3, user_id: @user.id, micropost_id: @micropost.id )
    create_list(:reading_list, 3, user_id: @another_user.id, micropost_id: @another_post.id)
   @reading_list_one = ReadingList.where(:user_id => @user.id)
   @reading_list_two = ReadingList.where(:user_id => @another_user.id)
  end

     let(:reading_lists) { @reading_list_one.map {|p| Micropost.find(p.micropost_id)} }

     let(:reading_lists_two) { @reading_list_two.map {|p| Micropost.find(p.micropost_id)} }


  it "assigns all the reading lists for user one to the @microposts" do
    get(:index, :user_id => @user.id)
    expect(reading_lists.size).to eq(3)
    expect(assigns['microposts'].to_a).to eq(reading_lists.to_a)
  end

  it "assigns all the reading lists for user two to the @microposts" do
    get(:index, :user_id => @another_user.id)
    expect(reading_lists_two.size).to eq(3)
    expect(assigns['microposts'].to_a).to eq(reading_lists_two.to_a)
  end
 end
end
```

Here is the index action in the reading_list controller.

```
def index
     reading_list = current_user.reading_lists
     @microposts = reading_list.map {|p| Micropost.find(p.micropost_id)}.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

Comment: Have you examined the value of `current_user` when you're running the second example to confirm it's really user two?

Comment: Peter, you are correct - my user is the one logged in from the code above, therefore it keeps bringing me back to that users reading list. I fixed this by logging in the another_user for the last test and it worked. If you redo your comment as an answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` typically returns the user who is logged in, in which case your `index` method will always return the microposts for whatever user is logged in by your `login_member` method in the outer `before` block.

You can get your test to pass by logging in as `@another_user` for that second test or by changing your `index` method to return microposts for the user identified in the URL.